# send message from bot to direct message after typing /slash command

Tags: python-3.x, django, bots, slack

I'm trying to make SlackBot and if I call him in some public channel it works fine but when I call him (type slash-command) in any direct channel I receive "The server responded with: {'ok': False, 'error': 'channel_not_found'}". In public channels where I've invited my bot it works fine, but if I type "/my-command" in any DM-channel I receive response in separate DM-channel with my bot. I expect to receive these responses in that DM-channel where I type the command.
Here is some part of my code:

```
if slack_command("/command"):
    self.open_quick_actions_message(user_id, channel_id)
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

def open_quick_actions_message(self, user, channel):
    """
        Opens message with quick actions.
    """
    slack_template = ActionsMessage()
    message = slack_template.get_quick_actions_payload(user=user)
    client.chat_postEphemeral(channel=channel, user=user, **message)
```

[Here are my Event Eubscriptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtlIn.png)

[Here are my Bot Token Scopes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYV0C.png)

Can anybody help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already solved my problem. Maybe it will help someone in the future. I've sent my payload as the immediate response as it was shown in the [docs](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/slash-commands#responding_immediate_response) and the `response_type` by default is set to `ephemeral`.

The part of my code looks like this now:

```
if slack_command("/command"):
    res = self.slack_template.get_quick_actions_payload(user_id)
    return Response(data=res, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
else:
    res = {"text": "Sorry, slash command didn't match. Please try again."}
    return Response(data=res, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Also I have an action-button and there I need to receive some response too. For this I used the `response_url`, here are the [docs](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/handling#message_responses), and the [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) library.

Part of this code is here:

```
if action.get("action_id", None) == "personal_settings_action":
    self.open_personal_settings_message(response_url)

def open_personal_settings_message(self, response_url):
    """
        Opens message with personal settings.
    """
    message = self.slack_template.get_personal_settings_payload()
    response = requests.post(f"{response_url}", data=json.dumps(message))
    try:
        response.raise_for_status()
    except Exception as e:
        log.error(f"personal settings message error: {e}")
```

P. S. It was my first question and first answer on StackOverflow, so don't judge me harshly.